# Change DNS using Powershell error

Tags: domain-name-system, powershell

I have this powershell script that changes the DNS settings. The below script works fine, but I want to filter by MAC address to make sure I'm changing the correct NIC.

---

$computer = "pc01"

$NICs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computer $computer -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE"

$DNSServers = "192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2"

foreach($NIC in $NICs) {
$NICs.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNSServers)

---

So I changed the filter to use the MACaddress. But I get the following error.

---

$computer = "pc01"

$NICs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computer $computer -Filter "MACAddress=00:1E:55:40:70:E8"

$DNSServers = "192.168.1.1","192.168.1.2"

foreach($NIC in $NICs) {
$NICs.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNSServers)

Output:

Invalid query 
+ $NICs = Get-WmiObject <<<<  -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computer $computer -Filter "MACAddress=00:1E:65:40:80:E4"

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
+ $NICs.SetDNSServerSearchOrder <<<< ($DNSServers)

Answer (score 1):

Try a Where clause for MAC Address:
$NICs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computer $computer | Where {$_.MACAddress -eq $MAC}

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Put the `'` marks around what is being filtered.  Using `-filter` is preferable over using `where {}` because of how the data is handled.  Using the `where {}` involves loading all the objects from the `Get-WmiObject` and then filtering them.  Using the `-filter` will do the filtering right away, so you end up with less data being worked through and less time to run the script.

```
$NICs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computer $computer -Filter "MACAddress='00:1E:55:40:70:E8'"
```